# How to echo value of a meta select box to the browser

Tags: post-meta

I think I'm echoing the value of the selected option from my select meta box wrongly. Nothing is being shown in the browser.

**Functions.php** :

```
function add_custom_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box(
        'custom_meta_box',
        'Custom Meta Box', 
        'show_custom_meta_box', 
        'post', 
        'normal', 
        'high'); 
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_custom_meta_box');



$prefix = 'custom_';
$custom_meta_fields = array(
    array(
        'label'=> 'Map Icon',
        'desc'  => 'A description for the field.',
        'id'    => $prefix.'select',
        'type'  => 'select',
        'options' => array (
            'one' => array (
                'label' => 'Option One',
                'value' => 'three'
            ),
            'two' => array (
                'label' => 'Option Two',
                'value' => 'two'
            ),
            'three' => array (
                'label' => 'Option Three',
                'value' => 'three'
            )
        )
    )
);

 function show_custom_meta_box() {
global $custom_meta_fields, $post;

echo '<input type="hidden" name="custom_meta_box_nonce" value="'.wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)).'" />';


    echo '<table class="form-table">';
    foreach ($custom_meta_fields as $field) {

        $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);

        echo '<tr>
                <th><label for="'.$field['id'].'">'.$field['label'].'</label></th>
                <td>';
                switch($field['type']) {

                    case 'select':
                        echo '<select name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'">';

                        foreach ($field['options'] as $option) {
                            echo '<option', $meta == $option['value'] ? ' selected="selected"' : '', ' value="'.$option['value'].'">'.$option['label'].'</option>';
                        }

                        echo '</select><br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';
                    break;
                } 
        echo '</td></tr>';
    } 
    echo '</table>'; 
}


function save_custom_meta($post_id) {
    global $custom_meta_fields;


    if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['custom_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__)))
        return $post_id;

    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
        return $post_id;

    if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {
        if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id))
            return $post_id;
        } elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
            return $post_id;
    }


    foreach ($custom_meta_fields as $field) {
        $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);
        $new = $_POST[$field['id']];
        if ($new && $new != $old) {
            update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);
        } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {
            delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);
        }
    } 
}

add_action('save_post', 'save_custom_meta');
```

**front-page.php:**

Copied  the  `get_post_meta` part from the codex, but doesn't seem to be working in the loop i'm using it in:

```
remove_action( 'genesis_loop', 'genesis_do_loop' );
add_action( 'genesis_loop', 'be_home_loop' );
function be_home_loop() {
 echo '<div id="pagewrap"> ';
echo '<div id="content">';
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    ?>
        <div class="entry">
        <?php the_title( '<h3>', '</h3>' ); ?>
            <?php the_content('read more &raquo;'); 
           $key_2_value =  get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'custom_meta_box', true );
  if( ! empty( $key_2_value )) {
  echo $key_2_value;
  }
```

Comment: I'm really tired, but here goes from what I can see. Your query is wrong. `while (have_posts()) : the_post();` should be `while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();`

Comment: @PieterGoosen Thank-you, I deleted the `$my_query` line, that shouldn't have been there. I have found an answer now (below), but don't understand why the code above doesn't work still. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got your "broken" code in your answer to work and will explain why. First, here's the edited code that wasn't working for you:

```
<?php

    //Get your post ID with a variable
    $this_post_id = get_the_ID();

    //Removed get function from get_post_meta to make functionality clearer
    //I tend to avoid nesting functions that are grabbing post information for easier debugging/reading
    //You need to use the field ID as the parameter in get_post_meta, what you had was the meta box id, not the field itself
    //Therefore WordPress didn't know what to retrieve since the metabox itself wasn't the custom meta you were grabbing
    $key_2_value =  get_post_meta( $this_post_id, 'custom_select', true );

    //Debugging got you an empty string before, uncomment this to see the results now
    //var_dump($key_2_value);

    if( ! empty( $key_2_value )) {
        //This works now - yay!
        echo $key_2_value;
    } ?>
```

The first thing I did was avoid nesting functions within functions so I made `get_the_ID` into a variable as well. It makes for easier reading and debugging should anything happen because then you can run `var_dump` on your variables piece by piece to confirm you're getting all the information you need when troubleshooting.

Running var_dump on `$key_2_value` gave me an empty string. I ran var_dump on `$this_post_id` which was working for the post ID, cool, then I realized something.

I changed this:

```
get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'custom_meta_box', true );
```

To this:

```
get_post_meta( $this_post_id, 'custom_select', true );
```

If you look at your functions file, in your `$custom_meta_fields` definition, you gave the select box an ID of "custom_select":

```
$prefix = 'custom_';    
$custom_meta_fields = array(
    array(
        'label'=> 'Map Icon',
        'desc'  => 'A description for the field.',
        'id'    => $prefix.'select', //right here!
        'type'  => 'select',
        'options' => array (
            'one' => array (
                'label' => 'Option One',
                'value' => 'three'
            ),
            'two' => array (
                'label' => 'Option Two',
                'value' => 'two'
            ),
            'three' => array (
                'label' => 'Option Three',
                'value' => 'three'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

So with [get_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta), the `$key` parameter is the ID of the post meta field. And so you had the name of your meta box, `custom_meta_box` there instead of the name of the actual field itself. Once I changed that to custom_select, it worked.

Hope that helped! :-)

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
$post_meta_data = get_post_custom($post->ID);
echo $post_meta_data['custom_select'][0];
```

Please can someone explain to me why this doesn't work? I know it doesn't, but not sure why

```
 $key_2_value =  get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'custom_meta_box', true );
  if( ! empty( $key_2_value )) {
  echo $key_2_value;
```

Comment: Do the a `var_dump()` to see what output you get from your variables and work according to that :-)

Comment: @mattnewbie I provided an answer explaining how to troubleshoot this and how I fixed it. Please take a look and let me know if it helps. Thanks.

Comment: @PieterGoosen Thank-you, I used `var_dump()` it's very useful. I shall be using it a lot . Thank you so much!!

Comment: @RachieVee  It makes perfect sense now. Really appreciated thank-you!!

Comment: @mattnewbie glad you got this solved. I abuse `var_dump()`. Without knowing a structure of a variable is like driving blindfolded. :-) . Enjoy